# How do I change my password in Trello?

Tags: trello, password-recovery

How can I change my Trello password? I couldn’t find an answer in their help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are able to log in:

- click on your initials at top-right of the Trello web page
- click on Account Settings
- click on Change Password
- enter old password, and then new password twice

And if you can't log in, email support@trello.com for help instead, as per the [Trello Help page](https://trello.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the option as mentioned in [other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/39648/87130). May be it is updated now, but this worked for me:

- Go to settings in Trello then
- Go to your Atlassian account option
- In Security option you can find the option of change password on top